# Reshaping data for use with geeglm()

Tags: r

Could you please help me figure out why I am getting an error?

Initially my data looks like this:

```
> attributes(compl)$names
 [1] "UserID"         "compl_bin"      "Sex.x"          "PHQ_base"       "PHQ_Surv1"      "PHQ_Surv2"      "PHQ_Surv3"    
 [8] "PHQ_Surv4"      "EFE"            "Neuro"          "Intervention.x" "depr0"          "error1_1.x"     "error1_2.x"   
[15] "error1_3.x"     "error1_4.x"     "stress0"        "stress1"        "stress2"        "stress3"        "stress4"      
[22] "hours1"         "hours2"         "hours3"         "hours4"         "subject"
```

First I reshape my data to prepare for geeglm:

```
compl$subject <- factor(rownames(compl))
nobs <- nrow(compl) 
compl_long <- reshape(compl, idvar = "subject",
                      varying = list(c("PHQ_Surv1", "PHQ_Surv2" ,
                                       "PHQ_Surv3", "PHQ_Surv4"), 
                                     c("error1_1.x", "error1_2.x",
                                       "error1_3.x", "error1_4.x"), 
                                     c("stress1", "stress2", "stress3",
                                       "stress4"), 
                                     c("hours1", "hours2", "hours3",
                                       "hours4")), 
                      v.names = c("PHQ", "error", "stress", "hours"),
                      times = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), direction = "long")
```

-(Editor's note: not sure what this next output is from...)

```
 [1] "UserID"         "compl_bin"      "Sex.x"          "PHQ_base"       "EFE"            "Neuro"          "Intervention.x"
 [8] "depr0"          "stress0"        "subject"        "time"           "PHQ"            "error"          "stress"       
[15] "hours"
```

Then I use geeglm function:

```
library(geepack)

geeSand=(geeglm(PHQ~as.factor(compl_bin) + Neuro+PHQ_base+as.factor(depr0) +
                    EFE+as.factor(Sex.x) + as.factor(error)+stress+hours,
                    family = poisson, data=compl_long,
                    id=subject, corst="exchangeable"))
```

I am getting an error:

```
"Error in geese.fit(xx, yy, id, offset, soffset, w, waves = waves, zsca,  : 
  nrow(zsca) and length(y) not match"
```

If I remove variables as.factor(error) and hours, geeglm does not complain, and I am getting the output. The function does not work with error and hours variables. I check the length of all the variables, they are equal. Could you please help me figure out what is wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: any chance of a reproducible example?  Do you have any `NA` values in your data?

Answer (score 3):

found this at: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-October/178337.html

> I'm pretty sure this is a bug in geese(), which should be reported to
> the
> maintainer of geepack.  The problem is with the treatment of missing
> values.
>
> If looks at `dim(na.omit(dat[,c("id","score","chem","time")]))` one
> gets 44.
> In geese.fit() zsca is set equal to matrix(1,N,1) where N is set
> equal to
> length(id).  But id has length 46 whereas the response y has been
> trimmed
> down to length 44 by eliminating any rows of the data where any of
> the variables
> involved are missing.  Hence a problem.
>
> The solution of the problem requires some code re-writing by the
> maintainer of geepack.